# Error when creating testTuple when writing unit test for apache storm bolt

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, mocking, apache-storm

I am trying to write unit test for one storm topology, I am using [Testing.testTuple](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.apache.storm.Testing&method=testTuple) to create test tuple which I will pass to execute method. I am not able to get this created and getting following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.scheduler.DefaultScheduler$loading__5340__auto____8214.invoke(DefaultScheduler.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.scheduler.DefaultScheduler__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.scheduler.DefaultScheduler__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5749)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$loading__5340__auto____8212.invoke(nimbus.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5832)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.testing$loading__5340__auto____8210.invoke(testing.clj:17)
    at org.apache.storm.testing__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.testing__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$loading__5340__auto____8208.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:17)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5832)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.testing4j$loading__5340__auto____11918.invoke(testing4j.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.testing4j__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.testing4j__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.Testing.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.abc.storm.bolts.IndexerBoltTest.add(IndexerBoltTest.scala:49)
```

Here is the piece of code throwing error:

```
val d = new IndexerBolt()
var cr: Option[MyObj] = None
import org.apache.storm.testing.MkTupleParam
val tupleParam = new MkTupleParam
tupleParam.setFields("value")
val t:Tuple = Testing.testTuple(util.Arrays.asList(cr.getJsonBytes), tupleParam)  <== This line
d.execute(t, c => cr = Some(c))
```

I am not sure how to fix these error, I am trying to setup the tests for the first time. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>provided test</scope>  //earlier it was only provided, I also tested with just test as well, which yielded same result
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>ring-cors</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also tried following, as suggested [here](https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/TestingApiDemo.java#L243), but same error:

```
tupleParam.setStream("value")
tupleParam.setComponent("value")
tupleParam.setFields("value")
val t:Tuple = Testing.testTuple(new Values(cr.getJsonBytes), tupleParam)
```

Comment: storm-core should be provided scope, so it's available when you test, but doesn't go in the jar when you build. Regarding the exception, it's coming from https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.2/storm-core/src/clj/org/apache/storm/config.clj#L78, which has to do with reading the Storm config. Is there a "Caused by" further down the stack trace?